Managing Tailwind CSS Configurations in Next.js Project: Overlapping Styles and Conflicts Between Multiple Configuration Files
I'm encountering an issue with managing Tailwind CSS configurations in my Next.js project. I have set up manually two separate Tailwind configurations for different parts of my application - tailwind.default.config.ts and tailwind.shad.config.ts (for shadcn). Each configuration defines distinct styles for specific components and themes.
In my CSS files (shad.css and style.css), I'm using the @config directive to specify the Tailwind configuration to apply. However, it seems that the configurations are overlapping or conflicting with each other, resulting in unexpected styling behavior.
Here's a simplified overview of my project structure and setup:
tailwind.default.config.ts: Defines default Tailwind CSS configuration for the project.
tailwind.shad.config.ts: Defines a separate Tailwind configuration for the shadcn components

I created manually two different tailwind configs in root directory ./
put my css files in the ./app directory
specify each tailwind file in the each css file

@config "../tailwind.shad.config.ts";
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;



import my css files in the main app/layout.ts

N.B :
**- I have same named css variables in each css file
**

I wish you have only given a path of your shadcn components to Content Configuration part of you tailwind.shad.config.ts file and not give that path in same key of different config file and also properly given the path of css file and tailwind config file into the component.json file

I installed it manually so i don't have the component.js and I think i don't need it at all, but thanks.
